# Flask app on plesk/apache server - how to change port?

Tags: python, apache, flask, gunicorn

I'm new to setting up a server for python apps, slowly getting my head round all the tools and config options.

I'd like to configure a testing instance on an existing server that has plesk and apache installed. I managed to set up the python environment, virtualenv, the flask app inclusive database and run it successfully on http://domain.test:5000 however I'd need to remove the port number from the domain.

Gunicorn seems to be the tool for that, however I'm not sure how to go about it as plesk is apparently installed on port 80 - so is there any way to get this configured on that server with some port hiding/masking/redirect or do I need to move to a standalone server?

Additionally I'd like to add a ssl certificate to that domain but one step at the time...

Answer (score -1):

The method `run` on a Flask application takes a keyword argument `port`:

```
from flask import Flask


app = Flask(__name__)
app.run(port=80)
```

Of course you'll need root privileges to run on port 80